# sql sum previous rows based on value of current row

Tags: sql, sql-update, common-table-expression, sql-server-2014

I have the following table

```
CREATE TABLE #tbl (
    RoomTypeId INT NOT NULL,
    DayNo TINYINT NOT NULL,
    RoomNo TINYINT NOT NULL,
    IsDormitory BIT,
    AdultsNo TINYINT NOT NULL,
    Tmp TINYINT)
insert into #tbl (RoomTypeId, DayNo, RoomNo, IsDormitory, AdultsNo, Tmp) values(2486, 98, 1, 1, 1, 0)
insert into #tbl (RoomTypeId, DayNo, RoomNo, IsDormitory, AdultsNo, Tmp) values(2486, 99, 1, 1, 1, 0)
insert into #tbl (RoomTypeId, DayNo, RoomNo, IsDormitory, AdultsNo, Tmp) values(2486, 98, 2, 1, 2, 0)
insert into #tbl (RoomTypeId, DayNo, RoomNo, IsDormitory, AdultsNo, Tmp) values(2486, 99, 2, 1, 2, 0)
insert into #tbl (RoomTypeId, DayNo, RoomNo, IsDormitory, AdultsNo, Tmp) values(2487, 98, 1, 0, 2, 0)
insert into #tbl (RoomTypeId, DayNo, RoomNo, IsDormitory, AdultsNo, Tmp) values(2487, 99, 1, 0, 2, 0)
```

Only for those rows with IsDormitory = 1, I want to update the field Tmp with values as follows: for each room having a certain RoomNo, the column Tmp = sum of all AdultsNo of all rooms having RoomNo <= current RoomNo.

Example:

- for room with RoomNo = 1, Tmp = 1 adult,
- for room with RoomNo = 2, Tmp = 3 adults, i.e. 1 adult (corresponding to RoomNo = 1) + 2 adults (corresponding to RoomNo = 2).

The result will be:

```
RoomTypeId  DayNo RoomNo  IsDormitory  AdultsNo Tmp
2486        98    1       1            1        1
2486        99    1       1            1        1
2486        98    2       1            2        3
2486        99    2       1            2        3 
2487        98    1       0            2        0
2487        99    1       0            2        0
```

The following did not work:

```
update #tmp2 set TmpAdults = Adults from #tmp2 t inner join 
(select RoomTypeId, DayNo, sum(AdultsNo) as Adults from #tmp2 x where      x.RoomNo  < t.RoomNo) s on t.RoomTypeId = s.RoomTypeId and t.DayNo = s.DayNo

;with CTE as
(
select RoomTypeId, DayNo, sum(AdultsNo) as Adults from #tmp2 group by RoomTypeId, DayNo
)
update #tmp2 set TmpAdults = c.Adults from #tmp2 t
inner join CTE c on t.RoomTypeId = c.RoomTypeId and t.DayNo = c.DayNo
```

I am using Microsoft SQL Server 2014.

I do not know how to use CTEs, but from what I read, this should be the answer. 
Thank you.

UPDATE:

I added 2 new rows:

```
insert into #tbl (RoomTypeId, DayNo, RoomNo, IsDormitory, AdultsNo, Tmp) values(2486, 98, 3, 1, 1, 0)
insert into #tbl (RoomTypeId, DayNo, RoomNo, IsDormitory, AdultsNo, Tmp) values(2486, 99, 3, 1, 1, 0)
```

but unfortunately the answer is not as I expect. I expect for RoomNo = 3 the Tmp = 1+2+1=4, instead I get 2

```
RoomTypeId  DayNo RoomNo  IsDormitory  AdultsNo Tmp
2486        98    3       1            1        4
2486        99    3       1            1        4
```

Comment: Which version of Sql Server are you using?

Comment: Are we only counting the AdultsNo once per RoomNo regardless of DayNo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This CTE should get you your results then it's simple enough to `JOIN` and perform the update.

Your use of multiple temporary tables concerns me though...

```
;WITH MyCTE AS
(
    SELECT
        RoomTypeID,
        DayNo,
        RoomNo,
        IsDormitory,
        AdultsNo,
        SUM(CASE WHEN IsDormitory = 1 THEN AdultsNo ELSE 0 END) OVER (PARTITION BY RoomTypeID, DayNo ORDER BY RoomNo ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) AS Tmp
    FROM
        #tbl
)
SELECT *
FROM MyCTE
```

Comment: This appears to be complete, it solved the problem. Thank you. Answer to other questions: For a certain RoomTypeId, RoomNo pair, the cumputed Tmp is the same for all DayNo rows.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `CTE` in order to update:

```
;WITH ToUpdate AS (
   SELECT t1.AdultsNo + COALESCE(t3.AdultsNo,0) AS AdultsNo,
          Tmp
   FROM #tbl AS t1
   OUTER APPLY (
      SELECT DISTINCT AdultsNo
      FROM #tbl AS t2
      WHERE t2.RoomNo < t1.RoomNo) AS t3
   WHERE IsDormitory = 1
)
UPDATE ToUpdate
SET Tmp = AdultsNo
```

The `CTE` uses an `OUTER APPLY` operation in order to fetch the `AdultsNo` values of previous records (if any).

Comment: Thank you. It worked. I'm struggling with this for hours. Question: I am developing on free edition of Microsoft SQL Server 2014, but I am going to deliver this to someone with different version, I think is an older version (unfortunately I do not know it now) . Will there be problems with the solution you provided me?

Comment: I think you need a sum() in your sub-query unless he only wants the single prior room in which case LAG would have been better.

Comment: Also OP says less than or equal.

Comment: @MihaiHangiu My query will work on SQL Server 2005+. You can change the `OUTER APPLY` any way you like to suit your actual business logic.

Answer (score 0):

```
update #tbl
set Tmp = (
    select sum(t2.AdultNo) from #tbl t2
    where t2.RoomTypeID = #tbl.RoomTypeID and t2.DayNo = #tbl.DayNo
        and t2.RoomNo <= #tbl.RoomNo
)
where IsDormitory = 1
```

I believe MySQL has problems referring to the same table in a subquery on an update but I'm pretty sure SQL Server has no problem with that. You could use an alias to correlate in the inner query but that's really not standard SQL. Note that the inner query is not limited to dormitory rooms as it's not clear from the question that that's what you needed.